# Why can I return this multiple elements in react without wrapping them in a fragment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

This code works fine in react and prints out all the names on page.
However I'm wondering it's returing multiple elements as a react component, Why is it working, shouldn't I wrap them in one fragment?

```
function App() {
  const names = ["jack", "taylor", "justin", "joy", "pink"];

  return names.map((name) => <h3>{name}</h3>);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Because It's returning a single array, which is (unsurprisingly) "a single thing" that React knows how to work with, just as if you'd returned a bunch of components wrapped in a fragment (or a div, or any other single, containing component).

Answer (score 1):

In React, as Fragment is used for grouping components. However, code works without wrapping the elements in Fragment because React internally used fragment to wrap array elements inside them.

In your code, there is an array of h3 elements and not explicitly wrapped inside Fragment or any Container element. So, React does it internally.

Refer [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment#reference) which specified that it is the same as if the elements were not grouped.

Well, Fragment is useful if you want to apply some style to group of elements.